VoiceOver rotor with non-tabbable elements
I just realized that VoiceOver's rotor isn't as practical as it could be. When I use it to navigate eg. to a particular heading, I'd expect it to move the native focus there as well, so that when I tab forward, I start right below the heading.
This however works only if the element I select in the rotor has an implicit or explicit tabindex. If it doesn't, the focus doesn't move and stays in the previous location. My questions are:

Is this by design, and is it even a problem?
What's the best technique for us developers to make it as smooth for screen reader users as possible.


That certainly is an interesting one. This is not how NVDA and JAWS behave on Windows, both of which move keyboard focus along with screen reader heading navigation features. But what you’ve observed is the behaviour for VoiceOver on iOS when browsing web content, which keeps the keyboard focus separate from VoiceOver’s virtual cursor. VoiceOver on macOS also exhibits this behaviour, except that it seems to reset keyboard focus to the top of the web content whenever heading navigation is used, which seems like a bug to me.
In iOS apps, Tab will continue to do the keyboard navigation behaviour of cycling through containers. In a web page, the expected web-like Tab navigation behaviour is used, and keyboard focus is separate from VoiceOver’s virtual cursor. Since Rotor navigation is a VoiceOver feature, I’m not surprised that keyboard focus isn’t moved by the browser, since the target element is not considered a focusable element without the use of a tabindex attribute. That’s why some skip link implementations fail: the skip link target is often not focusable. That said, it’s not how other screen reader software works.

It's surprising though since I've got the option to sync VO and native focus checked, but I guess, in browsers, it works only if the target element is focusable. Is there any way around that except for putting tabindex on all those headings?

Setting tabindex="-1" to make an element focusable or tabindex="0" to also insert the element in the page's tab order are the only techniques that I'm aware of.
